# Customize userinfo endpoint

Tags: ory

Is is possible to set output data/schema for userinfo endpoint?

Currently I have only this data

```
{
    "amr": [
        "password"
    ],
    "aud": [
        "32c4ec1f-e746-4e38-b6fa"
    ],
    "auth_time": 1710413228,
    "iat": 171042,
    "iss": "https://projects.oryapis.com",
    "rat": 171042,
    "sub": "c25169dc-6b64-4900-9a5"
}
```